# How many Premier League teams will play in the 17-18 Champions League?

Tags: football, english-premier-league, champions-league, europa-league

If Manchester United wins the Europa League, and Leicester City wins the Champions League (**everything is possible**), and both do not fall into the top 4 in the Premier League, then how many Premier League teams will play in the 2017-2018 Champions League?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/26087/3671

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No more than five clubs can enter the UEFA Champions League from one national association.**

> Regarding the top three associations (currently Spain, Germany and
>   England): if two clubs from one of these countries win the UEFA
>   Champions League and UEFA Europa League, and neither finish their
>   domestic league in a position that qualifies them for the UEFA
>   Champions League, the following will happen:
>
> – The club that won the UEFA Champions League will go straight into
>   the group stage.
>
> – The UEFA Europa League winners will go into the UEFA Champions
>   League play-offs.
>
> – The club that had qualified for a UEFA Champions League play-off
>   spot via their domestic league competition (i.e. finished fourth)
>   transfer to the UEFA Europa League.

Reference: [Uefa](http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuropaleague/news/newsid=2444525.html)

Comment: it is annoyance  to fourth team

Comment: Yeah, you have to  finish in top 3 to secure a place in UCL.